# i want to show the analytics dashboard in vf page

Tags: visualforce, einstein-analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards

I want to show the analytics dashboard in vf page ,but i have to show the dashboard dynamically based on the passing the dashboardId in url.please tell me how to show dynamically using dashboardId in Url

what i want is here iam using dashboardId statically when i preview it will open particalar dashboard.but i want to open dynamically based on user passing the dashboard Id in URL

```html
<apex:page >
    
  <wave:dashboard dashboardId="0FKDn000000XGqdOAG" height="800px"/>
    
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code. Here id has to be passed from the calling code as url parameter.

```
public class MyApexController {
public string myIDField;
public MyApexController(){
    myIDField  = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
    
}


public String waveId {
    get{
        return myIDField;
    }
}
```

}

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="MyApexController">
<wave:dashboard dashboardId="{!waveId}" height="800px"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: i tried this but it is not working throwing the error Neither the asset ID, developer name, or waveRoute are defined. Provide either the asset ID, developer name, or waveRoute for the asset.And i console id is null

Comment: Make sure that a valid Tableau CRM dashboard is present and copy its id. It should be  18-character code beginning with 0FK.